# How to define DTO classes of api and use them in Angular 7 SSR

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm setting up an angular application as a SPA of .net core web api. Thus, I have DTO classes which my rest api returns to my angular app. Since lack of SEO for Google's Angular2+ js framework, I needed to work with angular universal. my package.json dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.47",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "~7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
}
```

Since it's annoying to debug an angular application due to lack of useful error messages, its become even more annoying with SSR.

Here is the issue,

I have services which make http requests and returns the array of objects or single object or null, a classic rest api approach. Since we are using TypeScript, first I declared classes for my response objects which fail during compilation of SSR so I changed these definitions with interfaces but it didn't work either. Some examples of my interfaces are:

```
export interface Media{
    link?:string;
    alt?:string;    
}

export interface Category {    
    id:number;
    media?:Media;
    cultures?:CategoryCulture[];
}

export interface CategoryCulture{
    cultureId:number;
    name:string;
    generalDescription?:string;
}
```

When I import those in my component or service classes, I can use them as a Type identifiers. Standard

```
ng serve
```

runs OK and no problem shows up. But when I use

```
npm run build:prod;npm run server
```

An error shows up.

```
src/app/main/home/categories/categories.component.ts(3,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/models/category'.
```

further message says:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! LiderFinal@0.0.0 build:server:prod: `ng run LiderFinal:server && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LiderFinal@0.0.0 build:server:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T21_58_08_088Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! LiderFinal@0.0.0 build:prod: `npm run build:server:prod && npm run build:browser:prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the LiderFinal@0.0.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2019-05-08T21_58_08_119Z-debug.log
```

When I remove imports and use 'any' as type identifier on variables, it works. but that is annoying and I think that's why we use TS... Any help is appreciated, I'm in real trouble...

Comment: `Cannot find module 'src/app/models/category'` check your import paths